# Pass String array as input into external C function

Tags: modelica

I would like to pass a String vector into an external C function.

In a minimal example I just want to pass the String vectors (or 1D array) through the C function.

My Modelica function looks like:

```
function testreadstri
 input String instri[2];
 output String outstri[2];
 external "C" test_stri(instri,, size(instri, 1), outstri);
 annotation (Include="#include <ebcmysql.cpp>", Library="libmysql");
end testreadstri;
```

My C fucntion looks like:

```
void test_stri(const char* thestring, size_t nLines, const char **testresult)
{
    //bout = 12.3;

    size_t iLines;
    //size_t nLines;

    iLines = 0;
    //nLines = 1;

    while ( iLines <= nLines ) {

        <LINE_OF_INTEREST>
        iLines++;
    }
}
```

I tried for `<LINE_OF_INTEREST>` the following lines:

- `testresult[iLines] = thestring[iLines];`
- `strcpy(testresult[iLines], thestring[iLines]);`

What works, but of course does not pass the input through as an output, is:

- `testresult[iLines] = "aTestString";`

Is there any possibility to handle Modelica input String vectors in the external C function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [short, self-contained and compilable example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating both input string and output string handling of a pure external function in Modelica

```
model Model
  function testreadstri
    input String instri[2];
    output String outstri[2];
    external "C" test_stri(instri, size(instri, 1), outstri, size(outstri, 1));
    annotation(Include="
#include \"ModelicaUtilities.h\"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test_stri(const char** thestring, size_t nLinesIn, const char** testresult, size_t nLinesOut)
{
  size_t iLines;

  // example for input string handling
  for (iLines = 0; iLines < nLinesIn; iLines++) {
    ModelicaFormatMessage(\"%s\\n\", thestring[iLines]);
  }

  // example for output string handling
  for (iLines = 0; iLines < nLinesOut; iLines++) {
    char* line = ModelicaAllocateStringWithErrorReturn(6);
    if (line != NULL) {
      strcpy(line, \"result\");
      testresult[iLines] = line;
    }
  }
}");
  end testreadstri;
  String s[:] = testreadstri({"first", "second"});
end Model;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is supported by the Modelica specification, see https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#argument-type-mapping.

Comment: Thanks, @tbeu, I am aware of this section in the Modelica Specs. But how am I able to process the strings (or more correct char arrays) then in the C function? This might be a problem due to my rusty C skills ...